# /etc/gdm3/Prime and /etc/gdm3/PrimeOff in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gdm, etc

When are these files executed and what's their use?

Answer (score 0):

Search on https://packages.ubuntu.com gives [the following results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/gdm3/filelist): these files came from `gdm3` package, so they are executed on GDM (GNOME Display Manager) launch.

GDM is shown as login screen on every boot of Ubuntu system with GNOME.

The [contents of these files](https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/tree/debian/patches/ubuntu_nvidia_prime.patch?h=ubuntu/bionic) have references to [NVIDIA Prime](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME) executables:

```
$ cat /etc/gdm3/Prime/Default
#!/bin/sh

primeoffload=/sbin/prime-offload
if [ -f "$primeoffload" ]; then
    $primeoffload
fi

$ cat /etc/gdm3/PrimeOff/Default
#!/bin/sh

primeswitch=/sbin/prime-switch
if [ -f "$primeswitch" ]; then
    $primeswitch
fi
```

while `/sbin/prime-offload` and `/sbin/prime-switch` came from `nvidia-prime` package:

```
$ dpkg -S "/sbin/prime*"
nvidia-prime: /sbin/prime-switch
nvidia-prime: /sbin/prime-offload
```

but `/sbin/prime-switch` is not shown [on site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/nvidia-prime/filelist).